# Failed to send direct email message via aws Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to send email message to a specific email address via the aws pinpoint. My from email address is verified. However, whenever I try to send the email it gives me an error "Failed to submit email message to ". I don't understand where am I going wrong with this.

Comment: How are you trying to send your email? Console? API? Does your user have permissions? Have you enabled your email channel? What is the message you are trying to send? Are you using endpoint or address direct sending?

Comment: I am using the console. I have enabled all three channels, for push notification, email and sms. I am using address for it. But while I can send sms to intended numbers, the email is failing to be submitted. Also, I have adminstrator access for my account, so I don't think it is a permission issue.

Comment: Any guess on the following please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587214/pinpoint-gives-template-error-with-net-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Pinpoint provides an [sandbox environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-email-setup-production-access.html).

In order to send emails you need to white-list your from email address as well. ( i.e. got to SES and verify the from email id as well)

You should them be able to send emails via Pinpoint.

The receiver should acknowledge to terms and condition that AWS can send automated emails.

Comment: This is not the only problem. I can send a test message using SES from the same email address. However Pinpoint gave me "Message not sent: We weren't able to send your email message to someemail@gmail.com.
Request Id 982 : Failed to send message."

Answer (score 3):

@Krishna gave the right clue, however to be precise, **all** of the following must be true:

1. Your **From** email address is verified in Amazon Pinpoint/SES.
2. Either your **To** email address(es) is verified, **OR** you have requested [Sending Limit Increase **specifically for Amazon Pinpoint**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-email-manage-limits.html#channels-email-manage-limits-increase-case), not just SES.

In my case it was problem no. 2, I have increased my sending limit for **SES** but **not Pinpoint yet**. Amazon treats them somewhat differently, however the error message it gave me was totally undecipherable:

> Message not sent: We weren't able to send your email message to someemail@gmail.com. Request Id 982 : Failed to send message.

Specifically, check the Pinpoint project's right sidebar here:

[image: Pinpoint project]